# Imported existing CMake project into Netbeans 7.2, but No build options available

Tags: netbeans, cmake, netbeans-7, netbeans-7.2

I have imported a project built with CMake into Netbeans 7.2. I can succesfuuly build the project from netbeans, however:

1. I dont know what build configuration is being used (i.e. debug or release). I suspect it is a debug release due to the size of the built library.
2. How do I create Debug and Release builds for use in Netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the default build is indeed Debug.

To change the configuration to release, you need to invoke CMake with the command line argument `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`.

From what I recall, it's not possible to change configuration types easily from within the IDE, and [this bug report](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=187623) seems to indicate that this is still the case.